# Using "Include" Method for header in PHP & HTML

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to set all header inside 1 folder name header.php

So that everytime i can just use

```
<? php include ("header.php")?>
```

to set up all my stylesheet, JS and etc... 
but once i created a new file and create new php try to include my "header.php" it shows this error message

```
Warning: include(header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\WebEnt\Certain View File\Register.php on line 5

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'header.php' for 
inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\WebEnt\Certain View File\Register.php on line 5
```

header.php

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="Picture/SEGI2.png">
    <title>EC-Submission</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!--Own Customized CSS by Jake-->
    <link href="css/WebCustom.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

can anyone provide the easiest solution? Thank YOU

Comment: try include_once("header.php");

Comment: @NishitManjarawala Tried this the error message still the same, just from "include" became "include_once"

Comment: have you tried `require_once` ?

Comment: @Mazz tried, same error message

Comment: Is it in the same directory? Try `require_once(__DIR__."/../header.php") `

Comment: @Mazz it removed the error, but all the JS and CSS not working anymore... my css path was "css/WebCustom.css"

Comment: You can now either work with `__DIR__` or the root Path `/` ; Try to set your css via `/css/WebCustom.css` instead of `css/WebCustom.css`

Comment: In which directory is your css files? I mean the whole path

Comment: Here is it @TuomasK

C:\xampp\htdocs\WebEnt\css\WebCustom.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the problem with the CSS files, you need to use path

```
/WebEnt/css/WebCustom.css
```

or

```
/css/WebCustom.css
```

I'm not sure which one is working, but it's easy to test.

The explanation for this is that now the paths are in the HTML-code, which is processed only in browser while showing the page. Thereby the path must be relative to **the directory where the server is serving the pages from**. When you visit your site, I guess you go to address `http://localhost/`, that points to either `C:\xampp\htdocs\` or `C:\xampp\htdocs\WebEnt\`. That is what you need to take into consideration on the css path.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! After certain testing and with your answer i've successful solve this problem! I'll also provide the solution in this post.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided correct path for your header.php file, check in which folder is your header.php and correct its path in include

Comment: my "header.php" is placed at "htdocs\WebEnt" but the new php file is on "htdocs\WebEnt\Certain View File\Register.php" so is much deeper. By only using "include("header.php")" should be working... but not for me.

Comment: I think you need to use `C:\xampp\htdocs\WebEnt\header.php` I'm afraid PHP doesn't look back in the directory tree

Comment: @TuomasK I also tried this method, it will causing all my css not working.

Comment: I think there would be something wrong in your `header.php` file. Please update your question with new/more information or open a new question

Comment: @JakeCube In which folder is your css? Can you also list your directory structure of the project you are working on?

Comment: This is the file i working on.

C:\xampp\htdocs\WebEnt\Certain View File\Register.php

Comment: This is the file of CSS allocate
C:\xampp\htdocs\WebEnt\css\WebCustom.css

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution also thanks to whoever comment and help me to solve this issue. Here i'll list out how i solve this problem.

1. Create a external file to store **header, footer, navbar** and etc...
2. Changing the path from *"css/Webcustom.css" to "/WebEnt/css/WebCustom.css"*
3. Back to "*C:\xampp\htdocs\WebEnt\Certain View File\Register.php*" and changing the  include path via this method

   ```
   <?php include "$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/WebEnt/HVF/header.php"; ?>
   ```
4. And it works for me!